# quote generator without repeating not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to use the RandomQuoteGenerator Script and I found one on stackoverflow but I want it to not repeat the quotes, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536888/javascript-random-quote-generator-that-does-not-repeat-code) but it is not working for me. I am getting undefined error when clicking on the button. The original script provided in the above link is working fine but if I change the function as mentioned in the above link, I am getting undefined messages instead of quotes.

My Generator.js

```js
var quotes = [
//success quotes
  {
    quote: "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success.",
    source: "James Cameron",
    tag: "success"
  },
  {
    quote: "The Way Get Started Is To Quit Talking And Begin Doing",
    source: "Walt Disney",
    tag: "success"
  },
  {
    quote: "Don’t Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today.",
    source: "Will Rogers",
    tag: "success"
  },
  {
    quote: "We Generate Fears While We Sit. We Overcome Them By Action",
    source: "Dr. Henry Link",
    tag: "success"
  },

//health quotes
  {
    quote: "Early to bed and early to rise, makes a man healthy wealthy and wise.",
    source: "Benjamin Franklin",
    tag: "health"
  },
  {
    quote: "Let food be thy medicine and medicine be thy food.",
    source: "Hippocrates",
    tag: "health"
  },
  {
    quote: "If you can’t pronounce it, don’t eat it.",
    source: "Common Sense",
    tag: "health"
  },
  {
    quote: "Health is like money, we never have a true idea of its value until we lose it.",
    source: "Josh Billings",
    tag: "health"
  },

//spirituality quotes
  {
    quote: "Life is really simple, but men insist on making it complicated.",
    source: "Confucius",
    tag: "spirituality"
  },
  {
    quote: "My religion is very simple. My religion is kindness.",
    source: "Dalai Lama",
    tag: "spirituality"
  },
  {
    quote: "Knowing others is wisdom; knowing the self is enlightenment.",
    source: "Tao Te Ching",
    tag: "spirituality"
  },
  {
    quote: "When there is love in your heart, everything outside of you also becomes lovable.",
    source: "Veeresh",
    tag: "spirituality"
  }


];


document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, true);

//Sets up interval to show print qutoe every 15 seconds
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 15000);
function myCallback() {
  printQuote();
}

// Gets a random quote from array Quotes
function getRandomQuote () {
  return quotes.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length), 1);
}

//prints quote to html
function printQuote() {
  var getQuote = getRandomQuote();
  var message = '';
  message += '<p class ="quote">' + getQuote.quote  + '</p>';
  message += '<p class ="source">' + getQuote.source  + '</p>';
  message += '<p class ="tag">' + getQuote.tag  + '</p>';
  document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = message;
  newColor();
}
// function that will generate random color to the backgroun
var newColor = function randomColor() {
  document.body.style.background = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random Quotes</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="quote-box">
      <p class="quote">Be the change you wish to see in the world! </p>
      <p class="source">Ghandi </p>
    </div>
    <button id="loadQuote">Show another quote</button>
  </div>
  <script src="quotes.js"></script>
  <script src="generate.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just open the browser's developer tools and see what the first function is that is called. Then on it's second iteration look at the stack trace to see what initialized it's call the second, third, fourth, etc time.

Comment: function getRandomQuote() {
  return quotes.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length), 1)[0];
}

Comment: @D.Seth thanks it worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getRandomQuote()` returns an array so in order to access the object you need to access the first element of that array. Like this...

```
getQuote[0].quote
```

Comment: @AtulJha No problem. But you should take John's advice from comments and improve your debuging.